# Comparing row with prev row

Tags: sql, database, oracle, oracle10g

I'm trying to select once rows, that have (some specified) same values as the previous row.

I can select what I want like the following:

```
SELECT dpr_ts
       , dpr_open
       , dpr_volume
       , LAG(dpr_open, 1, 0) over(ORDER BY dpr_ts) AS po
       , LAG(dpr_close, 1, 0) over(ORDER BY dpr_ts) AS pc
       , LAG(dpr_volume, 1, 0) over(ORDER BY dpr_ts) AS pv
  FROM dpr
 ORDER BY dpr_ts;
```

How can I specifiy in where clause , that only the duplicates should appear?

I mean I want something like(this doent work, but putting it only to get you an idea what i'm trying):

```
SELECT dpr_ts
      , dpr_open
      , dpr_volume
      , LAG(dpr_open, 1, 0) over(ORDER BY dpr_ts) AS po
where po = dpr_volume;
```

Thanks
Greetings

Answer (score 3):

I think what you want is:

```
select *
  from (
    select dpr_ts
         , dpr_open
         , dpr_volume
         , LAG(dpr_open, 1, 0) over(ORDER BY dpr_ts) AS po
      from dpr
     order by drp_ts
    ) x
where x.po = x.dpr_volume
```